# Preparting environment for running a powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I needed to schedule a powershell script and before doing it, i needed to prep the environment by running some other powershell script.

Basically i wanted to run

PowerShell.exe  -noexit " & ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\sharepoint.ps1' "

PowerShell.exe  -command " & ' E:\PerfCounters\Powershell\RunPerf.ps1' "

The first statement will perp my environment and i want to execute my own script after that.

Issue is, if i use the -noexit command, the next script never gets executed. If i use -command instead of -noexit, the commands seems to be executed in different powershell instances so my second script is erroring out.

I am a newbee in powershell and i did my best tring to find a answer. Any help here would be really appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't solve this on your own, or if anyone else needs the syntax, here you go:

```
powershell -noprofile -command "& { & .\x.ps1; & .\z.ps1 }"
```